# Mobile Nav Isn't Showing Up on Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile, nav

### Live Site

https://www.safecolleges.com/

### Problem

Mobile nav works on all other devices and browsers except Safari.

### Description

I've looked around for some fixes and none of them seem to be working for me. I've tried giving the nav button to drop the navigation links `.hamburger { cursor: pointer }` along with any elements inside of it just to make sure.

I've tried using JS to force the menu to show when button is clicked/tapped by accessing the `style.display` property and changing it to `block` when clicked.

I've even tried to do some dirty inline JS on the button itself. `onclick="document.querySelector('.mobile-nav').style.display = 'block';"` and so far nothing is working.

The weird part is, the browser knows when a user "taps" the hamburger icon. If I set `alert('hello')` then I get an alert on the phone. But for some reason, the nav links will not show. Any solutions?

### Code

#### twig

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div id="mobilee-codde" class="navbar-header">

// This should be the only area that needs to be messed with
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed hamburger hamburger--slider" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#primary" aria-expanded="false" onclick="document.querySelector('.mobile-nav').style.display = 'block';">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="hamburger-box">
          <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="menu">MENU</span>
      </button>
// ends here

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="{{logo.url}}" alt="Safe Colleges Logo" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse desktop" id="primary">
      <div class="mobile-nav">
        {% include 'partials/mobile-menu.twig' %}
      </div>
      <div id="menu-barr">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <a href="/"><img src="{{logo.url}}" alt="Safe Colleges Logo" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9" style="padding:0;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {% for item in menu.get_items %}
        <li class="nav-item{% if item.title == 'Our Proven Solutions' or item.title == 'Hot Topics' or item.title == 'Success Stories' %} dropdown{% endif %}" data-target="{{ item.slug }}"><a href="{{ item.get_path }}" class="{{ item.class }} {{ item.current ? 'active' }} nav-link">{{ item.title }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" autocomplete="off" action="/">
            <div>
              <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
              <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
              <input type="image" src="/wp-content/uploads/search-icon-v2.svg" style="position: relative; top: 10px; color: white; height: 22px; width: 22px;" name="search" alt="Search" class="button" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/free-trial/" class="free-trial-link nav-link">Free Trial</a></li>
      </ul>
            </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-drop our-proven-solutions-dropdown" bacon-style="equalHeight" bacon-target=".heading, .item">
        {% for product in proven_solutions_dropdown %}
          <li>
            <a href="{{ product.button_link }}"><h4 class="heading">{{ product.heading }}</h4>
            <div class="item">{{ product.copy|wpautop }}</div>
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">{{ product.button_copy }}</span></a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav-drop hot-topics-dropdown">
        <li>
          <a href="/hot-topics/active-shooter-topic"><img src="/assets/images/target.png" alt="" style="margin-left:-7px; margin-right:10px;" /><h4>Active Shooter</h4></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/hot-topics/clery-act"><img src="/assets/images/shield.png" alt="" /><h4>Clery Act</h4></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/hot-topics/ghs-compliance-training-prevent-campus-accidents/"><img src="/assets/images/flask.png" alt="" /><h4>GHS Compliance</h4></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/hot-topics/save-act-training-students"><img src="/assets/images/student.png" alt="" style="margin-left:-5px; margin-right:13px;" /><h4>Save Act</h4></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/hot-topics/title-ix-training-faculty"><img src="/assets/images/books.png" alt="" /><h4>Title IX</h4></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/hot-topics/vawa"><img src="/assets/images/user.png" alt="" style="margin-right:18px;" /><h4>VAWA</h4></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav-drop testimonials-dropdown" style="display: none;">
        <li>
          <a href="/university-of-north-dakota-case-study-2/"><h4>University of North Dakota Case Study</h4></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/fairmont-state-meeting-title-ix-mandates-for-staff-students/"><h4>Fairmont State Case Study</h4></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/forsyth-tech-case-study/"><h4>Forsyth Tech Case Study</h4></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>







{# <header class="page-header container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="brand" role="banner">
      <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="{{logo.url}}" alt="Safe Colleges Logo"></a>
    </h1>
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--slider" data-toggle="collapse" type="button" data-target="#primary" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="hamburger-box">
        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
      </span>
    </button>
    <nav class="navbar primary-navigation container collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {% for item in menu.get_items %}
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{ item.get_path }}" class="{{ item.class }} {{ item.current ? 'active' }} nav-link">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" autocomplete="off" action="/">
            <div>
              <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
              <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
              <input type="image" src="/assets/images/magnifying-glass.png" name="search" alt="Search" class="button" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="free-trial-link nav-link">Free Trial</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header> #}
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your site and I was able to get it working in safari by removing `z-index:0;` from the class `.navbar-default #primary` it still seems to work in chrome as well.

this was the offending div too

```
<div class="navbar-collapse desktop collapse in" id="primary" aria-expanded="true" style="">
```

not sure if this is the best solution since I am not sure if you control the css or are using a library.

Comment: I dont seem to be able to edit the file that creates that `z-index`. More like I cant find it but is there another `z-index` that will work or is removing it my only option here?

Comment: Looks like its fixed on your site. Is that correct?

Comment: What are you using to test this? Im on a trial version of browserstack and its not working, iphone 6 ios 9, but youre saying its working for you on safari?

Comment: I was using the mobile view on safari browser on my mac. I was able to reproduce your issue there, but now i can't. I do still see your problem on my iphone 6

Comment: I just added some arbitrary value to the `z-index`, think it's set at `auto` now. The CSS file in devtools says its coming from `index:551`, not sure where thats at for me to edit it. This is a WordPress site just to be specific.

Comment: I see `.navbar-default #primary { z-index: auto !important;}` now which is overriding the z index described in my answer so I think that is why its working now on the safari browser through my macbook

Comment: Okay, so you are confirming it IS working on your iPhone?

Comment: no just my browser on my macbook. You can try wraping that css you added with `@media screen and (max-width: 992px){  } `

Comment: so it should look like `@media screen and (max-width: 992px){ .navbar-default #primary { z-index: auto !important; } }`

Comment: although I am not sure if that max-width is auto calculated somehow